# Можно ли как-то с помощью css сделать смену src=""? Пояснение читайте ниже

Tags: javascript, html, css

у меня есть кнопка:

```
<button class="theme-btn" id="theme-btn"> <img src="images/theme-btn.png"> </button>
```

она нужна для смены темы сайта, набросал простой скрипт:

```
    $(function(){
            $('button.theme-btn').click(function(){
            $('#header').toggleClass('light')
            $('#body').toggleClass('light')
            $('#theme-btn').attr('src', '../images/light.png')
        });
    });
```

наверно некоторые уже поняли, что я хочу сделать. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы изображение менялось каждый раз при клике на кнопку, в css пока не вижу никакой возможности это сделать. Если сам найду ответ, скину его сюда, может он на поверхности лежит. Оно должно меняться, как на примере с классами выше, то есть сначала меняется на одно изображение, потом в изначальное. UPD: добавил кнопку в **отдельный див**, всё получилось и стало в 32131 раз проще.

Comment: Вариант раз: делайте две картинки и через css скрывайте лишнюю. Вариант два: вместо тега img используйте стиль background-image

Comment: скрывать это display: none? или как

Comment: А ещё ваш скрипт не должен работать, потому что он пытается менять src не у картинки, а у кнопки

Comment: изображение и должно быть кнопкой по идее

Comment: но уточнение по факту, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
button .image {
  background: url("https://sdtimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/ts-logo-256.png");
  background-size: cover
}

button:active .image {
   background: url("https://hsto.org/webt/61/8e/0d/618e0d50e1954906733801.png");
   background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<button
  id="my-btn"
  style="width:100%"
>
  <div
    class="image"
    style="width: 100px; height: 100px"
  ></div>
</button>
```

Comment: очень близко к правде, спасибо!

Comment: @Данила Под вопросом есть комментарий от `andreymal`. Можно и кнопку стилизовать. Да, можно вообще всё одним дивом реализовать. Или написать свой кастомный тег.

Comment: @Данила А что не хватает для принятия ответа?

Comment: извините, забыл совсем, нечасто тут сижу, просто пока ещё свой вариант решению продумываю